# Android theming: Set Status Bar color to Action Bar color in Material3

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I am migrating my app's Material Design theme from V2 (1.4.0) to V3 (1.5.0).

Unlike `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`, which had a DarkActionBar sub style that used the Primary color for the Action Bar, `Theme.Material3.DayNight` doesn't have DarkActionBar sub style.

I can't figure out what color is used for the Action Bar in the default settings.

This is how my current app theme shows up:

[image: App screenshot]

As can be seen, my Primary color is Blue, but the Action Bar has automatically been colored using a shade/alpha of the primary. The hexadecimal color notation of the Action Bar was not defined by me. I tried setting the Status Bar to all the various shades of blue that I defined in my colors.xml file, but none of them are a perfect match.

Can someone explain how is the Action Bar color determined or how I may be able to set the Status Bar to the same color as the Action Bar?

**colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>

    <color name="black_alpha_020">#33000000</color>
    <color name="white_alpha_060">#99ffffff</color>

    <color name="blue_50">#e3f2fd</color>
    <color name="blue_50_bit_black">#E4F0F5</color>
    <color name="blue_100">#bbdefb</color>
    <color name="blue_300">#64b5f6</color>
    <color name="blue_500">#2196f3</color>
    <color name="blue_700">#1976d2</color>
    <color name="blue_a100">#82b1ff</color>

    <color name="blue_black_3_3">#072451</color>
    <color name="blue_black_3_3_bit_black">#031228</color>
    <color name="blue_white_5_6">#fafdff</color>
    <color name="blue_black_5_6">#061929</color>
    <color name="blue_black_10_2">#CEDCE6</color>
    <color name="blue500_black_5_6">#26282A</color>

    <color name="blue_50_alpha_060">#99e3f2fd</color>

    <color name="blue_grey_700">#455a64</color>
    <color name="blue_grey_800">#37474f</color>

    <color name="amber_100">#ffecb3</color>
    <color name="amber_700">#ffa000</color>
    <color name="amber_black_3_4">#401C00</color>

    <color name="red_50">#ffebee</color>
    <color name="red_black_2_3">#3D0909</color>
    <color name="red_900">#b71c1c</color>

    <color name="grey_600">#757575</color>

</resources>
```

**themes.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.SimpleTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
        <!--Color-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/blue_50</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/blue_black_3_3</item>

        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue_grey_800</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/blue_50_bit_black</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/blue_black_3_3_bit_black</item>

        <item name="colorTertiary">@color/amber_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorTertiaryContainer">@color/amber_100</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiaryContainer">@color/amber_black_3_4</item>

        <item name="colorError">@color/red_900</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorErrorContainer">@color/red_50</item>
        <item name="colorOnErrorContainer">@color/red_black_2_3</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/blue_white_5_6</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/blue_black_5_6</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/blue_white_5_6</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/blue_black_5_6</item>

        <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/blue_black_10_2</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/blue500_black_5_6</item>
        <item name="colorOutline">@color/grey_600</item>

        <item name="colorSurfaceInverse">@color/blue_black_5_6</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/blue_white_5_6</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryInverse">@color/blue_a100</item>

        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">?attr/colorSurface</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.SimpleTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 20):

Make your status bar transparent:

themes.xml

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

themes.xml (night)

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
```

Edit your activity_main.xml file like below sample code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        ...>

        <com.google.android.material.MaterialToolbar
        ...
        />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    ...
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For more information, check this doc: https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/implementation/android#collapsing-top-app-bars

Comment: Doc page cannot be found

Comment: @kitfist0 Github doc: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TopAppBar.md#collapsing-top-app-bars

Comment: This is the only right answer on this whole page.

Answer (score 14):

**Using SurfaceColors class**

The color of the Action Bar is colorSurface with elevation.

If you want to change the color of the Status Bar. Using [SurfaceColors](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/elevation/SurfaceColors.java) class. This function also works with Dynamic Coloring in Material 3 and day/night mode.

Code in Kotlin

```
val color = SurfaceColors.SURFACE_2.getColor(this)
window.statusBarColor = color // Set color of system statusBar same as ActionBar
window.navigationBarColor = color // Set color of system navigationBar same as BottomNavigationView
```

Result
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the status bar in Material 3 have colorSurface, i.e. SURFACE_0? Examples show that the color of the status bar should obviously be identical to the one of the top app bar (SURFACE_0, i.e. colorSurface, unless scrolling): https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/specs

Comment: @Patrick. There are two ways to implement top app bars: ActionBar and Toolbar. My answer is based on the default ActionBar. You can see there is a little shadow under the app bars. And your comment is based on Toolbar. Which need manually set and add. We were both right. Here is the link to the difference between these. https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Comment: For java use getWindow().setStatusBarColor(SurfaceColors.SURFACE_2.getColor(this)); and also set <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item> for themes.xml and <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item> for themes.xml (night)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to do the following in `themes.xml`.

This worked for both light and dark themes:

```xml
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked wor me.

Add this item to your style in the theme.xml file:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
```

Comment: Don't forget dark theme if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

I override the action bar styles in my theme:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.BusyAllInOneShopping" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/accent_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" >?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton</item>
    </style>
```

When I hover "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" in themes.xml of my previous project, it shows the default styles
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**theme.xml(no-night):**

```
<style name="Theme.AllCodeApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/white</item>
         <item name="actionBarStyle">
            @style/MyActionBarDarkStyle
        </item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarDarkStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary">
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

**theme.xml(night):**

```
<style name="Theme.AllCodeApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">
            @style/MyActionBarDarkStyle
        </item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarDarkStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary">
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/teal_200</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I know how to set a colour. I need to figure out what colour is set automatically for the action bar and preferably set the status bar colour using attributes

Comment: ok got it my code is update check it

Comment: I am actually using Material V3 (Theme.Material3) not V2 (Theme.MaterialComponents). The parent themes that you had in your code don't exist anymore. I tried something similar to what you had in your code though, and it didn't work. Setting textColor and titleTextColor didn't change the Action Bar style either. Wonder if it is a bug.

Comment: send me your theme light  and dark file

Comment: tomorrow i will see. today my exam

Answer (score 0):

The parent theme what you are using has an attribute colorSurface and this attribute is responsible for the background color of the action bar. But in material3 , primary colored elevation are applied to surface color to create a mixed color . Refer this link below and read the section **Using Surface Colors** carefully , you'll get your answer. [Here is the link](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/color-theming).

As that color is generated dynamically, you can set the the status bar color for your app dynamically using SurfaceColors Api .

In java `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(SurfaceColors.SURFACE_5.getColor(this));`

I have used enum SURFACE_5 above for example purpose , you can use different enums from SURFACE_0 to SURFACE-5 , to get the desired color.